# SSH Connection Timed Out - TryHackMe Linux Walkthrough

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I am a beginner trying to learn Linux from TryHackMe's Linux Fundamentals. I ran out of time on the attack box and have been trying to connect to my active machine using a VPN over OpenVPN Connect.

Unfortunately, I am stuck with a connection timeout when trying to ssh into my active machine.

I have followed the instructions on the webpage to download OpenVPN Connect and the configuration file. The website even confirms that I am successfully connected to their network.

```
ssh -v  tryhackme@10.10.229.160

OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for * 
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling 
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.229.160 [10.10.229.160] port 22. 
debug1: connect to address 10.10.229.160 port 22: Operation timed out 
ssh: connect to host 10.10.229.160 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Above is what the terminal throws back at me. I have tried changing servers and also uninstalling and reinstalling OpenDNS Connect, but to no avail.

Hoping you can provide some insight!

Comment: Could be down? I get a timeout as well doing this: `ssh -v  tryhackme@10.10.229.160`

Comment: Sounds like a firewall stopping connections on port 22 and/or SSH is not running on 10.10.229.160.

Comment: “The website even confirms that I am successfully connected to their network.” - The output of your connection attempts say otherwise